# Google Maps info windows only displays info from the first click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a script that:

1. pulls results from a database in the form of an XML file
2. parses those results
3. creates a marker for each result and places it on a map (a single map for all markers)
4. at the same times, builds a clickable HTML list (sidebar) containing all those results.

When the user clicks on a place name in the sidebar, the info window from the corresponding marker on the map is automatically displayed. Of course the user can also click directly on a marker on the map, and the same info window is also displayed.

**This code has been working fine for several years**, but last week I noticed that its behavior was now bugged. When viewing some given results, the **first** click (either on the map or in the sidebar) works fine (the info window opens and displays the correct information), but **the following clicks all show the same information from the *first* click**, all in their respective info window. (To be clear: the information shown is the one from the very first click, not from the previous click.)

I've been trying to debug that for hours but I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore. As you can see in my code below, I tried adding a `console.log` in the `google.maps.event.addListener` function, to see what data is being worked with when the marker is clicked, but even there, I don't see anything wrong.

Here is my code (simplified to be more readable):

```
var side_bar_html = '\n';
var gmarkers = []; // array for created markers
var infoWindow;
var center_lat = <?php echo $position_lat; ?>;
var center_lng = <?php echo $position_lng; ?>;

function createMarker(point, name, html, place_id, map) {
    var marker, markerOptions;
    markerOptions = {
        map: map,
        position: point,
        dataId: place_id,
        icon  : 'theme/marker.png',
        shadow: 'theme/marker_shadow.png'
    };
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        console.log(this, marker, html);
        infoWindow.content = html;
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });

    gmarkers.push(marker);
    side_bar_html += '\n<li><a href="javascript:showPlace(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')" id="sr' + place_id + '">' + name + '</a></li>';
    return marker;
}

function showPlace(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
}

function loadEarth(opt, zoom) {
    var map, point, mapCenter, mapOptions;
    if (zoom === null) {zoom = 7;}
    mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(center_lat, center_lng);
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: mapCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map   = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(center_lat), parseFloat(center_lng));
    if (opt != 0) {
        map.setMap(new google.maps.Marker(point));
    }
}

// receiving results via XML
function go() {
    var map, bounds;
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    $.ajax({
        url : 'url/to/data.xml',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'xml',
        success : function(xml) {
            var markers, lat, lng, place_id, point, label, html, marker;
            markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                // extract data for each marker
                lat =     parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
                lng =     parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                place_id = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("place_id"));
                point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                label = $(markers[i]).find('label').eq(0).text();
                html  = $(markers[i]).find('infowindow').eq(0).text();

                // marker creation
                marker = createMarker(point, label, html, place_id, map);
                // extend visible zone to newly added marker
                bounds.extend(point);
            }
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(center_lat, center_lng), 7);
            bounds.extend(point);
            if (markers.length>0) {
                document.getElementById("side_results").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
            } else {
                loadEarth();
            }
        } // end AJAX success
    }); // end AJAX
} // end go()

if ($('#places_page').is('.empty')) {
    loadEarth(0,8);
} else go();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

As requested, here's a sample of the XML received. In this case, the PHP variables at the start of the script would receive the following values:

$position_lat: 46.9479222
$position_lng: 7.4446085

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><markers>
<marker place_id="955" lat="46.950218" lng="7.442429">
    <label><![CDATA[<em>Place 955</em><strong>3011 Bern</strong>]]></label>
    <infowindow>
        <![CDATA[<p><em>Place 955</em><br />Speichergasse 35<br />3011 <ins>Bern</ins></p>]]>
    </infowindow>
</marker>
<marker place_id="985" lat="46.942032" lng="7.389993">
    <label><![CDATA[<em>Place 985</em><strong>3018 Bern</strong>]]></label>
    <infowindow>
        <![CDATA[<p><em>Place 985</em><br />Brünnenstrasse 106A<br />3018 <ins>Bern</ins></p>]]>
    </infowindow>
</marker>
</markers>
```

The Google Maps API is included via this line:
`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&language=fr&key=..."></script>`

**Edit 2:**

Changing the API call to force it to use version 3.18 *does fix the problem*:
`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=true&language=fr&key=..."></script>`

Obviously this is a temporary fix, since v. 3.18 won't always be available. Now I need to understand what change in the 3.19 version made this bug appear. Any suggestion is still appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you provide sample xml (a snippet to run your code with, so it will demonstrate the issue)?  How are you including the API (are you using the experimental version or some other version)?  [My (admittedly very simple) example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) seems to work OK.

Comment: OK, I've edited my question to answer your questions. I don't think the problem comes from parsing the XML, because the first click does work, and as far as I can tell, every marker in the XML is correctly retrieved in the ajax success function . (I will test that again, to be sure.)

Comment: (Your link isn't responding, by the way. (Connection times out.))

Comment: *Note:* yup, I console.logged it and I can confirm that all markers info are correctly extracted from the XML file in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This undocumented usage:

```
infoWindow.content = html;
```

May be the issue.  Should be:

```
infoWindow.setContent(html);
```

The .content property went away or is no longer supported [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7641)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I corrected that, but it didn't fix my problem. It's interesting to know that the February update broke some things, though. I'll check complete change log to see if I find any clue. Or maybe I could change the API call to force using the previous version? (Not sure if it's possible, I'll try.)

Comment: Oh, my bad, that was indeed the cause of the problem! But in my full code I use that line in two places, and at first I had only corrected one of them. Correcting them both fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!